# Compile java to objective c with j2objc with jre emulation lib from terminal only

Tags: java, terminal, emulation, j2objc

Hi i would like to convert my java code to objective c from terminal with j2objc.

I need to set below flag in terminal. (jre_emul is J2ObjC's JRE emulation library).

```
-ljre_emul
```

So when compile j2objc should compile with the JRE emulation lib.

```
$ j2objc Hello.java
```

How can i do it with terminal only without Xcode?

Source reference
https://github.com/google/j2objc/wiki/Xcode-Build-Rules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You jumped ahead in the wiki, as the Getting Started page is for a command-line:

https://github.com/google/j2objc/wiki/Getting-Started.

```
$ j2objc Hello.java  # translates to Hello.m, Hello.h
$ j2objcc Hello.m    # compiles, links to a.out
$ ./a.out Hello      # run binary, specify the class name (like java command)
Hello, world
```

The j2objc and j2objcc commands are scripts, so you can also use them to see what defaults are used. For example, the "-ljre_emul" flag is set by j2objcc.

There are man pages for all commands, so running "man -M /man j2objcc" will show its documentation.